# Add text formatting tags to xml doc

Tags: xml, f#, documentation-generation

I was wondering if it would be possible to add text formatting (layout) tags to a xml doc.

For example:

```
...

/// <summary>
/// This method is <bold>important</bold> and it does: <%Go to a new line%>
/// - take an input <%Go to a new line%>
/// - produce an output </summary>
member this.MyMethod () = 

...
```

Thank you.

Comment: It *should* [work pretty much the same as it does for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx), take a look at [`<list>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ww3c7e.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I had a look. `list` should work, but what about a `<br>` equivalent and eventually a `bolding` tag?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but I'm no expert on XML docs.

Comment: [FSharp.Formatting](http://tpetricek.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/metadata.html) has a docs generator that works with markdown in the comments. That might give you more options for formatting than you get with the default Xml comments.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what tool you use for producing documentation. The F#-compiler just spits out whatever tags you put in there.

In principle, the markup in your source code should be all logical, indicating only the function of the elements. Their presentation should be left up to whatever tool produces output from the logical markup.

That said, in C#, adding a `<para>` tag is a popular way to achieve line breaks. For your particular example, it looks like `<list>` is what you're after.